# the git hooks post-update seems not working

Tags: git, bash, centos

I want my git server can checkout automatically,
so I try to use the
.git/hooks/post-update
the content is

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /htdocs
git reset --hard HEAD
```

but it didn't work
so i created a script on my server which includes such command
and in the file "post-update" i wrote

```
/bin/bash /cron/git  #git is the script
```

when I run the script in bash,it works,but when i push to the git , it dosn't work.

the git version on my server is  2.4.0
and i use centos 6  x64
the permission of script is 4755 and belongs to root:root
the permission of ./git is 750 and belongs to git:git

Comment: Are you pushing directly to `/htdocs`, or to another repository on the system?

Comment: yes,after i pushed ,i try to run the script in command,and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `GIT_WORK_TREE=.. git reset --hard`.